# CSS3 loading animation component in Angular 2

Tags: css, angular

I'm starting to learn how do do animations with CSS3, here's my first [animation](https://plnkr.co/edit/ugQKPxeXaqI3cYIpsYJb?p=preview).

I have placed it between my `<root>` tag in my `Angular4` application and it works !

But I wish to package it in an Angular component for reuse, can that be achieved? How can a loading component be loaded before anything else in order to... display a loading animation?

Comment: To achieve re-usability you can make an angular component. But if you will do so, you will be unnable place this component inside the root

Comment: Therefore I should place the root inside this component? Should my module be on the loader's level then?

Comment: the root component is for bootstrapping your app. I believe you cannot wrap root by your component

Comment: Okay, then how will the loading component be loaded and displayed before the root ?

Comment: I think if any server rendering not needed, you probably can place this loader aside of root, and when the app will be bootstrapped you can hide this loader from the app

Comment: But then that's not very reusable right? I'll need an `*ngIf` and a boolean.

Comment: Kinda. You can dublicate loader in a component and re-use it across the app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you want to show this when loading some async data. In that case, you can just add your HTML/CSS to a component and control its visibility with an input variable.

In this example, it will be shown by default, then you can hide it after your data is resolved.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'spinner',
  templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.scss']
})
export class ItemsListComponent {

  @Input() showSpinner: boolean = true;

  constructor() { }


}
```

In your spinner.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showSpinner" class="lds-cube">
  <!-- the rest of your html -->
</div>
```

Then you can show or hide the spinner from any parent component by passing it a boolean variable that you set to true after the data is loaded.

```
<spinner [showSpinner]="yourBoolean"></spinner>
```

Here's an article about using a [spinner component](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/show-loading-spinners-for-firebase-data/) for async data from Firebase, but would work same with any data stream.

**Showing a Spinner Before the App has Loaded**

Your app will not have access to its components at this point, so I think it's best to use plain CSS. Add a div with a loading class in index.html.

```
<app-root></app-root>
<div class="loading">
  <h1>~$ loading app...</h1>
 <!-- your animation html -->
</div>
```

Then in your main stylesheet, you can use the pseudo `:empty` selector to show the loading content when the app-root empty.

```
.loading {
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #272c33;
    padding-top: 25vh;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-out;
}
app-root:empty + .loading {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I wish to have a splash screen loading animation, that loads before my root component and displays an animation

Comment: I updated my answer, you can do that with just plain CSS. You can't do that with a component because that puts the cart before the horse.

Comment: So far I do it with plain css, okay, it's good to know that it is not possible, thank you !